# does not download file

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream

i use the following code to download file from specified url using socket not url.openconnection();
after downloading when i checked it was not working... when i open the file with editor it was completely blank no data inside the file(empty file ) need suggestion ???... ...

```
try {

    String address="http://tineye.com/images/widgets/mona.jpg";
    URL url_of_file=new URL(addres);
    String hostaddress=url_of_file.getHost();
    Socket mysocket=new Socket(hostaddress, 80);
    System.out.println("Socket opened to " + hostaddress + "\n");
    String file=url_of_file.getFile();
    System.out.println(" file = "+file);

    OutputStreamWriter osw=new OutputStreamWriter(mysocket.getOutputStream());

    osw.write("GET " + file + " HTTP/1.0\r\n\n"); 
    osw.flush(); 

    dis = new DataInputStream(mysocket.getInputStream());
    fileData = new byte[7850];

    for (int x = 0; fileData[x] > 0; x++){
         fileData[x] = (byte) dis.read();
    }

     // close the data input stream
    fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\down-to\\filedownloaded.jgp"));  //create an object representing the file we want to save
    fos.write(fileData);  // write out the file we want to save.
    dis.close();
    fos.close();

} catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Check.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Check.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: Please rephrase your question.

Answer (score 5):

Is this:

```
for(int x=0;fileData[x]>0;x++){
```

right ? It looks like you're trying to break based upon the content of the stream. As Flavio has indicated, this statement is false immediately since the array is newly created.

I think you're much more likely to read the indicated length of the content, or until the end of the stream is reached.

In fact, I'd much rather use an existing [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/) and bypass all of the above. Writing reliable HTTP code is not as trivial as it first appears and 3rd party library will save you a lot of grief.

Comment: @Adel - No worries! Thank you. Was beginning to wonder if I'd misread the question

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a few things wrong. First of all it's reinventing the wheel, since lots of HTTP libraries already exist.

Then you're crafting an invalid HTTP request. Just like HTTP 1.1, the headers of such a request should be ended with a `\r\n`, while you only send an `\n`:

```
osw.write("GET " + file + " HTTP/1.0\r\n\n");
```

The server will probably wait until you finish your request (it's still waiting for a complete request, ended with a double `\r\n`) or throw an error since it does not expect the second `\n` there.

Then you're not reading the response headers, which may indicate how much data to expect. It's funny you initialize a byte array that's exactly large enough (the file you want to download is 7850 bytes large), but you can't hardcode file sizes for every file on the web, since you'll soonly run out of disk space storing them.

So, either read and parse a `Content-length` header or wait for the server to close the connection after sending all data (those are the two options in [HTTP 1.0](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.0/draft-ietf-http-spec.html#BodyLength)).

Finally you're not reading the response correctly, as pointed out by others. Please get these basics fixed, then you can try to store the response. Now your file is filled with zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

What is the meaning of the `for` condition?

```
for(int x=0;fileData[x]>0;x++){
```

The fileData array was just created, so it is filled with zeroes. `fileData[x]>0` is immediately false.

Answer (score 0):

By modifying your code as below I was able to fill the file with data and here is what i got:

> ERROR: Access Denied
>
> ## ERROR
>
> ### Access Denied
>
> ---
>
> - **Access
>     Denied by security policy**
>
> The security policy for
>   your network prevents your request from being allowed at this time. 
>   Please contact your administrator if you feel this is incorrect.

```
try {
    String address = "http://tineye.com/images/widgets/mona.jpg";
    URL url_of_file = new URL(address);
    String hostaddress = url_of_file.getHost();
    Socket mysocket = new Socket(hostaddress, 80);
    System.out.println("Socket opened to " + hostaddress + "\n");
    String file = url_of_file.getFile();
    System.out.println(" file = " + file);

    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(mysocket.getOutputStream());

    osw.write("GET " + file + " HTTP/1.0\r\n\n");
    osw.flush();

    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(mysocket.getInputStream());
    byte[] fileData = new byte[7850];
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\aboutros\\Desktop\\filedownloaded.jgp")); // create an object representing the file we want to save

    while (dis.read(fileData) >= 0) {
        fos.write(fileData); // write out the file we want to save.
    }
    dis.close();
    fos.close();

} catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this condition correct? If yes what's the meaning behind this condition?

```
for(int x=0;fileData[x]>0;x++)
```